# In Sublime Text, how do I find and replace, for example </strong></em> with </strong></em> followed by a carriage return?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, find-replace

[image]

I'm trying to add a carriage return after a combination of closing tags throughout my document in Sublime text. How do I either non-manually put multiple cursors after every instance of a search term OR Replace a series of search terms with the same search terms, but followed by a carriage return?

For example  with  (carriage return).

Comment: I don't have any experience with ST2 (which is why this is a comment) but in ST3 you can use `\n` in your replacement field to signify a new line, so this would be something like `((?:</\w+?>)+)` replaced with `\1\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the "Regular Expression" toggle is enabled on the left side of the find replace section
2. Find what: "`</strong></em>`"
3. Replace with: "`</strong></em>\n`"

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I tried that, but instead of add a carriage return, Sublime is adding a space. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: I added a screenshot so you can see if our toggles are set the same

Comment: Thanks. I think my Sublime is misbehaving.